# Blank screen while loading Fragment from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I am working on a application where I have one fragment `(HomeFragment)` in this fragment I have multiple `Grids` if I click on any of this `Grid` application will redirect to an `Activity` using `Intent` Like below

```
Intent calendarIntent = new Intent( getContext(), CalendarActivity.class );
List<Audit> lst = response.body();
calendarIntent.putExtra("calendarData", (Serializable)lst);
startActivity( calendarIntent );
```

In this Activity I have a `Home button`on toolbar on click of this `Home Button` I have to call `HomeFragment` like below

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_home:
                Fragment mFragment = new HomeFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main, mFragment)
                        .commit();
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected( item );

        }
    }
```

Basically the flow is
`HomeFragment -> Activity -> Activity -> Activity (load HomeFragment)`

But when I load `HomeFragment` from my activity I am getting blank screen for some seconds before `HomeFragment` is loaded,
Any idea how to remove this blank screen.

link for video
[video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13dNtVaTROnycuvgfIqbVG2ULp-Mb-8K6/view?usp=sharing)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried changing .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main, mFragment) with .add(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main, mFragment) in  onOptionsItemSelected ?

Comment: yes I tried, blank screen is still coming @SoufianeKre

Comment: is it possible to show me a video on how this behavior occurs ?

Comment: @SoufianeKre added video link in question

Comment: You are loading the Fragment into which activity ? because i see that you are loading the fragment & destroying the current activity ? did you call the Home activity before loading Home fragment?

Comment: Found the Solution, HomeFragment is loading in MainActivity so I called MainActivity from my last Activity, and its loading perfectly. @SoufianeKre
Thanks for the Help